# typeError: a byte-like object is required, not 'str' in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I am experimenting things. I am trying to solve this UDP client and server program in python3 using python socket.

The objective of my UDP server program named UDpserver.py are as follows:

- Receives a message from a client
- Responds to the client with the same message but all in UPPER CASE.

The objective of a client program named UDpclient.py that connects to above server and receives a response from the server:

- sends a message to the server
- Display the message received from the server. The displayed message should be in upper case.

following is the server program's code (UDpserver.py):

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
print (“The server is ready to receive”)
while 1:
 message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
 modifiedMessage = message.upper()
 serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

Following is the client program code(UDpclient.py)

```
import socket
serverName = ‘hostname’
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
 socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message = input(’Input lowercase sentence:’)
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print modifiedMessage
clientSocket.close()
```

When I run the client program(Udpclient.py) I get this error after it lets me input lowercase letters:

*TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'* for line 7 i.e
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))

[TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4FhL.jpg)

If anybody could please help me solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Please post the actual traceback. We're all used to them.

Comment: Please post your **actual** code. The code you’ve posted is invalid Python because it uses the wrong quote characters for strings.

Comment: because **socket.sendto** actually expects bytes to be passed along with the address. For more info see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto

Comment: @KonradRudolph - That's unfortunately common when you paste into a word processor before reposting here. Finding a text editor that doesn't mess things up can be a challenge.

Comment: @tdelaney I’m aware. But, pardon me, that stuff about it being a challenge to find a text editor is nonsense: they’re a dime a dozen and every good beginner course mentions at least one. No idea who teaches using word processors to edit code, it’s such a bizarre thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `message.encode()` to encode the string type message. So this is how your `UDPclient.py` would look like:

```
import socket
serverName = ‘hostname’
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,
 socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message = input(’Input lowercase sentence:’)
clientSocket.sendto(message.encode(),(serverName, serverPort))
modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)
print modifiedMessage
clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I updated my code with message.encode() and now I  am getting this error:

File "UDpclient.py", line 7, in <module>
clientSocket.sendto(message.encode(),(serverName, serverPort))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: try passing the actual IP of hostname instead of "hostname" e.g 127.0.0.1

Comment: `gaierror` means that there is no IP address associated with the server name you gave in `servername`. Refer to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238610/what-is-the-meaning-of-gaierror-errno-3-temporary-failure-in-name-resolutio/40238730) for more information. In short, you can fix it by giving the IP address of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 strings fully support the unicode specification. An in-memory string must be serialized in some way to conform to some sort of encoding such as ASCII, UTF-8, various Windows code pages and etc, before being sent on the network. `sendto` expects an already-encoded bytes string.

Since you are transfering data between machines, its not a good idea to let each one choose its own encoding. The easiest option for a home grown protocol is to just declare that you will use UTF-8, which is the most interoperable unicode encoding.

```
clientSocket.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"),(serverName, serverPort))
```

The receiver would decode using the same encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After updating with the code you mention i got this error _File "UDpclient.py", line 7, in <module> clientSocket.sendto(message.encode("utf-8"),(serverName, serverPort)) socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution_

Comment: That means DNS had an error trying to resolve the target host name. Can you ping the host from the command line? There are lots of causes such as firewalls, the computer's time being wrong, name registration issues with dhcp or mdns.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it after changing 'hostname' to actual IP and updating the error code with

```
clientSocket.sendto(message.encode(),(serverName, serverPort))
```